# Assistance with a validation rule

Tags: validation

I have a request from one of my business units to require 3 fields have a value when another field has a specific value.

```
IE: When case.Status_Type__c (picklist)= "BR Verified On-Site"
then the following 3 fields ALL need to be populated:

MFG_Year__c (Text)
Boiler_Type__c (Picklist)
Fuel_Type__c (Picklist)
```

I know I can do this with 3 separate validation rules but was wondering if anyone knew how to create 1 rule that will accomodate all scenarios?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should cover it:

```
AND(TEXT(Status_Type__c) = 'BR Verified On-Site',
    OR(ISBLANK(MFG_Year__c),
       ISBLANK(TEXT(Boiler_Type__c)),
       ISBLANK(TEXT(Fuel_Type__c))))
```